# Recurring Events for Document Creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, schedule

I have been spinning my head on this one for a few days now. I need the ability to pull documents from my Mongo Database on a scheduled time period to create a copy of the document (without the time schedule).

Example:

Schedule: Every 30 weeks on Monday, Wednesday, and Saturday

Document:

```
{
  _id: 'abcxyz',
  service: 'HVAC',
  assignedTo: 'xyzabc',
  details: 'Check HVAC System for problems'
}
```

I will have a multitude of documents with all different time schedules. Some with things such as the first Monday of every third month (quarterly).

I have tried using things such as later-js but later js doesn't seem to understand things such as `30 weeks`, which I think is because `30 weeks` isn't something you would normally do with a crontab.

In order to complete this, I'm assuming I would generate the `nextRunDate` and pull each doc that has the `nextRunDate` of today. With this being said I'd then need to calculate the `nextRunDate` every time which I feel like would be tough todo if the current run date was the first `Monday` How would you calculate to make the next run date to be Wednesday instead of 30 weeks from now?

Anyways I would insanely grateful for any assistance with this issue. If what I said above is confusing I believe it would be very similar to the google calendar scheduler.

[image: Google Calendar Scheduler]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through many libraries I found that both momentjs and later-js are missing pieces to make this possible. However functionally momentjs provides most of the tools required.

momentjs was lacking the ability to target the a particular day of the week i.e. Monday especially in the context of the first Monday of a month.

later-js is missing the ability to schedule say 30 weeks out as it does not have a `every(30).weeks()` option.

My solution was to create a way to find the `first Monday of a month` outside of moment as well as calculate the next recurring date.

Here is the code to do so

```
import moment from 'moment';

/**
 * Gets the first week day of type in a month
 * @param  {Date} date    the original date
 * @param  {Number} day   the day of the week we are looking for
 * @return {Date}         the new date object
 */
const getFirstWeekDay = (date = new Date(), day = 0) => {
  // set the date to the first of the month
  date.setDate(1);

  // Get the first weekday of the month
  while (date.getDay() !== day) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  // return the new date
  return date;
};

/**
 * Returns a starting point
 * @param  {Date} startDate   the date to start from
 * @return {moment}           a moment object
 */
const start = (startDate) => moment(startDate).startOf('day');

/**
 * Calculates a Schedule on a weekly basis
 * @param  {Date}    startDate   the date to start from
 * @param  {Array}   days        days of the week to create
 * @param  {Number}  weeks       number of weeks for recurrance
 * @return {Date}                the next run date
 */
const weekly = ({ startDate, days, weeks }) => {
  const today = start(startDate);
  const index = _.indexOf(days, today.day());
  if (index === (days.length - 1)) {
    return today.add(weeks, 'weeks').day(days[0]).toDate();
  }

  return today.day(days[index + 1]).toDate();
};

/**
 * Calculates a Schedule on a monthly basis
 * @param  {Date}    startDate   the date to start from
 * @param  {Number}  day         day of the week or month
 * @param  {Number}  months      number of months for recurrance
 * @param  {Boolean} weekDay     starting at weekday or date
 * @return {Date}                the next run date
 */
const monthly = ({ startDate, day, months, weekDay }) => {
  const next = start(startDate).startOf('month').add(months, 'months');
  if (weekDay) {
    return getFirstWeekDay(next.toDate(), day);
  }

  return next.date(day).toDate();
};

// register the function in a object so we can find them
const schedules = {
  weekly,
  monthly,
};

/**
 * Returns the next run date based on a config
 * @param  {Object} config      the config for recurrence
 * @return {Date}               the next run date
 */
export default (config) => schedules[config.type](config);
```

You can use this as follows

```
  // this will get the next date 2 months out on the 30th of the month
  console.log(
    getSchedule({
      type: 'monthly', 
      months: 2,
      day: 30,
    })
  );
  // this will get the next date 2 months out on the first Wednesday
  // of the month
  console.log(
    getSchedule({
      type: 'monthly',
      months: 2,
      day: 3,
      weekDay: true,
    })
  );
  // this will get the next date 30 weeks out and if it is Monday it will
  // instead of creating another date 30 weeks out it will create a new date 
  // for Wednesday. Once Wednesday comes it will then find the next Monday 
  // that is 30 weeks out
  console.log(
    getSchedule({
      type: 'weekly',
      weeks: 30,
      days: [1, 3],
      startDate: moment().add(1, 'weeks'),
    })
  );
```